# Libqt 5 based applications have big icons and fonts and scaling issues

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, qt5, vlc, scaling

Since I updated to QT 5 (Ubuntu 16.04), all applications (VLC, TexStudio, Texmaker ...) that use QT 5 have problems scaling, and every time I disconnect my laptop from the external screen , the incons and fonts are big and pixalated.

If any one had the same issue or is familiar with the problem, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you ask this question in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Not yet, Apparently it's not specific to ubuntu as it affects other distributions like fedora and other, it may be a QT 5 bug.